# How can I recieve and treat data from a cURL call

Tags: php, rest, curl

I have to send a json response from a cURL call.
The user send me a "test" variable to file.php.

On my php file, I use this code

```
$arr = array($arr = array('test' => 'ok'));
echo json_encode($arr);
```

And this for the cURL call

```
curl --request POST http://www.domain.com/WS/file.php -d '{ "test" : "12341234123412342" }'
```

Here is the answer

```
[{"test":null}]
```

What's the good way to get de POST variable and treat it in my php file?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Just in case, the problem comes from the cURL call. Here's the correct syntax:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"test\":\"12341234123412342\"}" http://www.domain.com/WS/file.php
```

Comment: you just want to get a variable from POST? Use $_POST http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Answer (score 0):

Ur question is kinda confusing :)

so ur User sends u a variable in file.php
and u have to curl with that variable ?

why not just

```
curl --request POST http://www.domain.com/WS/file.php -d '{ "test" : "$_POST['USER_INPUT_VALUE']" }'
```

or am i missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.

You're right, it might be confusing. I have to add some new details and give a better example.

The user execute that script in a file test_curl.php:

```
// test_curl.php

$url = "http://www.domain.com/WS/file.php";
$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$data = array(
    'test' => '12345'
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
$contents = curl_exec($ch);

echo $contents;

curl_close($ch);
```

Here's the file.php

```
// file.php

$arr = array($arr = array('test' => $_POST['test']));
echo json_encode($arr);
```

I recieve the POST variable and it works. Here's what $contents recieve in test_curl.php

```
{"test" => "12345"}
```

New fact, it works with test_curl.php. I've got the good answer but when do it in command line with that code...

```
curl --request POST http://www.domain.com/WS/file.php -d '{ "test" : "12345" }'
```

...I've got this answer:

```
[{"test":null}]
```

And finally, my question is why the response is *null* when I make my call in command line?

Answer (score 0):

That won't work.

In your post data you are sending a `json/application` content type. Inside the server, you are expecting content from a variable called `test`, which should only exists in a normal form key valued body, which is not the case.

So, you need to `json_decode` directly the raw body of the post data content, then access the `test` key inside it, as such:

```
$raw_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json = json_decode($raw_body);

$arr = array($arr = array('test' => $json['test']);
echo json_encode($arr);
```